# Numbers: Export CSV with different separator

Tags: csv, export, iwork-numbers

In a Mac when you export CSV files they always put a comma separator, this can break really bad the documents.

Is there a way to export with different separator (like '\' or 'tab')?

Even better, is there a way to making this by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export as TSV instead of CSV. TSV is Tab Separated Values, so it's exactly what you're looking for.

[image: image of menu item]

Comment: Glup! Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 3):

For those who want to export from numbers to csv with separators other than ones that numbers choose for you (and tabs) e.g. semicolons. Also if you want to quote your csv columns e.g. with double quotes.

The painless method is to open file in Libre office and export to csv from there. Choose 'Save As', select 'Text CSV', and tick 'edit filter settings' you will be able to set field delimeter and string delimeter in the following dialog. Note that only active sheet will be exported.

I was trying to convert spreadsheet to csv with comma separated, quoted columns in Numbers prior to finding this solution, I think it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Guess what the C in CSV stands for? ;)

Joking aside, according to the [Convert Numbers spreadsheets to PDF, Microsoft Excel, and more](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205391) Apple Support page, while Numbers can open a tab-delimited file, it isn't able to export to such a file itself.

Your only options from within Numbers are as follow:

- Numbers ’09
- Microsoft Excel: Office Open XML (.xlsx) and Office 97 or later (.xls)
- PDF
- Comma Separated Values (.csv)

Several suggestions I have seen suggest trying the following:

- Copy the table into Pages
- From within Pages, Format > Table > Convert Table to Text
- The new file can be Exported as Plain Text and will now be tab-delimited.

Comment: Well you are right, I should ask Apple and Microsoft to accept TSV files (Tab Separated Values). ;). I mean, in 2020 is frustrating not having this option, when you work with long files and you want to import is pretty magical using a (|) as separator, cause commas are always in texts. Thanks for your suggestions btw ;)